# ngClick but prevent any active inputs from losing focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular view I have an input field and some clickable goodies using ng-click.

Is there an angular way or simple vanilla  js way to prevent the input field from LOSING focus (if it was in focus) when one of these ng-clicks is clicked?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="foo">

<button ng-click="someThing()">click me</button>
```

Comment: call ` $(pattern).focus() ` in the method used in your ng-click ;) for example in ` someThing() `

Comment: Why do you want that it should not loose focus?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not with `ng-click`, because by the time that fires, the clicked element has already taken the focus from the input.

But `ng-mousedown` should work, if you `$event.preventDefault()` in your event handler.  Here's a demonstration in vanilla JS; the same should work in Angular:

```js
    var preventBlur = function(event) {
      console.log("click");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

```html
    <input type='text' onblur="alert('blurred')">
    <button onmousedown="preventBlur(event)">Click</button>
```

If you click the button while the input field is in focus, the mousedown will trigger without causing the input field to lose focus.

Comment: and it will not loose the position in the textarea or whatever. Better solution than .focus (argh)

Comment: This is perfect and translated to Angular ngMousedown wonderfully! Thank you good sir.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use javascript

```
$scope.someThing = function () {
    //implementation...
    document.getElementById("yourInputIt").focus();
};
```

Comment: implementation should come BEFORE the focus call, if the element #yourInputIt is dependant on a $scope variable, it will be removed then a new will be added by angular = focus LOST.

Comment: Note: if the $scope.someThing contains an ajax call with jquery, and that there is a $scope.$apply in the code, you have to place the .focus() call at the $scope.$apply end because the $apply is async.